# Eclipse Maven Integration archetype is not on the list

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-luna

I am following Java Brains' Maven tutorials to learn maven. In the tutorials, when creating a new `Maven Project`, and searching "**webapp**", there will be an artifact with an id "**javaee6**" (and many others).

[image]

However, in my case, I only see 2 archetypes:

[image]

I am using Eclipse Luna (4.4.1) with the latest version of **Eclipse Maven Integration**.
What is wrong here, and how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These archetypes are available in maven central. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

To add this catalog go to: Window / Preferences / Maven / Archetype / Add Remote Catalog...